# Docker file fails to build

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, manjaro

I am a software developer by trade. I know little about linux and general networking but I do use `docker` a lot.

About a month ago I dual booted. I now have Manjaro Linux and Windows 10.

I am working on a pet-project. I have the following [Dockerfile](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Elm/blob/feature/dockerise/Dockerfile). On my Manjaro Linux when I run `docker build . --no-cache` the dockerfile fails to build. The error I get is this:

[image: dockerfile build fail on linux]

When I run the same command on Windows, the dockerfile builds without any problems. Also, someone else running Manjaro linux ran the same command, and for them it built fine too, even on Linux.

This means the issue it local to my machine, something is not right in my Manjaro install. The install is fresh about a month old so I'm not sure what can be wrong.

I ran `sudo iptables -nL` to see what I have, here is the output:

[image: iptables]

I read the official docker documentation on iptables, and it tells users not to mess with the docker chains.

I'm now stuck and I'm not sure why my dockerfile is failing.

Answer (score 0):

This error is covered in their forums here: https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/cannot-install-any-elm-packages/3084

Copying answers for archival:

1:

> At the end of the error message it says the URL doesn’t exist. So this looks like a networking issue. Maybe test if you can reach the same URL from the same box using curl or wget or a browser. Maybe it’s behind a firewall or you need to set HTTPS_PROXY in the environment?

2:

> https://package.elm-lang.org is not set up for ipv6 (I just tested). So you need to change the protocol to v4.

3:

> 1. ping package.elm-lang.org
> 2. Adds the ip into /etc/hosts

The first thing I recommend trying is disabling IPv6 in Manjaro (if you have it enabled).

Comment: I disabled IPv6 and still got [the same problem](https://i.imgur.com/oEQt9yt.png).

Comment: @J86 Can you run `curl` on that URL and see if it is successful?

Comment: I just did. The curl was a success, but it still failed on the build step. [Here's the output](https://gist.github.com/JwanKhalaf/8fef57728c27327629c32a7be16cb180).

Comment: Can you check that `systemd-resolved` is symlinked to `resolv.conf`? This should force everything to use the the `systemd` DNS stub file.

Running the following should take care of this:
`# ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Reference:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved#DNS

Comment: How do I check that it is linked? I tried doing `file /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved` and it tells me that the file is dynamically linked, but [it doesn't tell me](https://gist.github.com/JwanKhalaf/632ad59835f2ef4971b9e9fedba28d64) where it is linked to. Also that reference you linked to says I ought to have `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` but I don't! [See here](https://gist.github.com/JwanKhalaf/510dc9f2c7f194b18369be10e89d070b).

Comment: You stated that others don't experience the same issue as you. Are you able to have them check if that file exists on their system, and if it is symlinked? Also, you could follow the Configuration steps on that page to setup that file on your system: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved#Configuration